# XMLHttpRequest, No Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the requested resource

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

I facing the below issue, I am hitting a file on a different server that is 3000 from 7777. Platform is node.js?

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/register_user. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:7777' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Cross Domain requests are aren't allowed in your node.js script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was needed it for only one domain

```
var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.orgigin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');  

    next();
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can control this via HTTP header by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Setting it to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` will accept cross-domain AJAX requests from any domain.

Try to add this in your app.js file

```
var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');  

    next();
};
```

and then  use like this:-

```
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Comment: thanks mohit. it's working but what is "p3p". The last two iines

Comment: @DineshRawat you should accept as answer if it helps so that can help to other users